# Legacy employee management system heavily using ActiveX

Tags: javascript, oracle11g, activex

At my office, we use a legacy JS system that only works on Internet Explorer due to ActiveX depedency when performing System-to-System communication.

How would I even start to convert it into a cross-browser system that can be put up on an internal server and gain access to. I mainly do backend work but have been tasked to save this old application which is ActiveX dependent.

I am not searching for code solutions but just in general ways to accomplish this move from Internet Explorer only to Cross-browser functionality. The application is only written in JS and is very old (10+ years).

I use ActiveX in my JS to retrieve data from an Oracle 11g database. I have considered using Java Restful Web Services and JAX-RS with a tomcat server but I do not know if that is the answer.

Code example of ActiveX use:

```
var xls    = new ActiveXObject ( "Excel.Application" )
var handle = xls.Workbooks.Add

var arrayOverskrift = new Array('INITIALER','TEAMNAVN','UDDANNELSE_NAVN','UDD_START','UDD_SLUT')
var i=0
//Indsætter overskrift
for (j=0;j<arrayOverskrift.length;j++)
{
        value = arrayOverskrift[j]
        xls.Cells( i+1, j+1).Value = value
}
    i++
var y = arrayOverskrift.length

while(rs.eof != true)
{
    for (j=0;j<arrayOverskrift.length;j++)
    {
        value = replaceNullFromDatabase(""+rs(arrayOverskrift[j]))

        xls.Cells( i+1, j+1).Value = value
    }
    i++
    rs.moveNext
}
    rs.close()
    conn.close()
```

//  To make it display in its own window
   xls.visible = true

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and check out [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask) and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic) I'm afraid this is far too broad for an SO question. If you're mostly a backend person, I strongly recommend farming the project out to a team that has frontend experience. (There will need to be both frontend and backend aspects to this, you can't directly access your DB from browser-based JS cross-browser.) Either way, good luck with the project!

Comment: I am the only one on my team who is tasked with this. Is it correct that I can solve this using Java Restful Web Services + JAX-RS with a tomcat server deployed locally?

Comment: Probably, provided you configure it to allow cross-origin requests from the webpage (I'm assuming the web page is hosted on one host, and your tomcat server will be on another host or at least another port, so [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) will be required).

Comment: wouldn't this mean a complete rewrite. It's a huge project they should have started a decade ago?

Comment: It may well; but it may not, too. It depends on how the old code is written. If the only IE-specific code is the ActiveX accessing the DB, it should be possible to keep the changes fairly targeted. If the IE-isms are all over, that's going to be more work. I'd definitely flag up for management that this is a **non-trivial** task. FWIW, if my team were doing this (and without wishing to be intrusive, we have availability), we'd evaluate Node.js vs. Java for the server piece so we could reuse the existing JS DB code. But it really depends (on a lot of things, including your in-house expertise).

Comment: I see. This seems more complicated than I was told the more response I get from the Intenret. I included a code piece from 1 out of 10 JS files in the program that uses ActiveX.

Comment: Ah, so you have Office automation as well as DB access. Yes, very much a non-trivial project.

Comment: So what do you mean by this being a non-trivial project? Any ideas of how to move on from here?

Comment: I mean it won't be a simple, small project. It will require a fair bit of work. In terms of moving on, that's a bit of a "how long is a piece of string" question. You'll need to figure out how to do the things it currently does in ways that are standards-compliant. The DB stuff will need to be moved to a server, probably the Office automation parts, too. Or maybe you replace the whole thing with a non-browser-based solution.

Comment: FWIW, and it's just my opinion, but someone who doesn't have much browser-based development expertise is really going to struggle with doing this in a browser-based environment. It's not entry-level stuff at all. If none of your colleagues has that expertise, I'd say you're better off outsourcing it. (I'd be saying that even if I didn't run a firm that does this kind of outsourced work, but naturally you have to consider the fact that I *do* run such a firm when evaluating my comment. :-) ) Whatever you do, good luck with the project!